# How to add a Redis AUTH token to a ElastiCache via a CloudFormation template?

Tags: redis, aws-cloudformation, amazon-elasticache

I'm setting up a new Redis ElastiCache stack and need help adding an AUTH token as an added layer of security. What is the parameter that I should add when using a CloudFormation template to deploy the stack?

I haven't been able to find any documentation regarding this, hence would appreciate if someone could help.

**[Update]**

After adding the `AuthToken` param, I'm seeing the error *"Encountered unsupported property AuthToken"* on the CloudFormation console.

Comment: Can you please post your cloudformation template? That would help the community to understand the problem better.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Answering my own question here in case someone comes across the same issue.

You need to use Replication Groups and not Cache Clusters if you need an ElastiCache Redis instance with AUTH enabled. Remember to enabled in-transit encryption as well since they both go hand in hand.

Comment: Thanks for answering, Could please post your cfn as well, That would be really helpful!